# Can not catch error clause

Tags: erlang

I am trying to read a file and when any error occurs, it should match pattern and return value

My code looks like

```
read(File) ->
  try file:read_file(File) of
    {ok, Content} -> Content
  catch
    error:E -> {"Error reading", File, E};
    _:_     -> {allError}
  end.
```

and when I run, I see

```
1> file_read:read("/Users/harith/Downloads/er.txt").
<<"This file is read by erlang program\n">>
2> file_read:read("non-existent-file").
** exception error: no try clause matching {error,enoent}
     in function  file_read:read/1 (/Users/harith/code/IdeaProjects/others/erlang/programmingErlang/src/file_read.erl, line 16)
3>
```

Why is it not catching the most generic clause `_:_`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
read_file(Filename) -> {ok, Binary} | {error, Reason}
```

Please read the doc: http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#read_file-1

The `{error,enoent}` is the result of `file:read_file(File)`, is you should write:

```
 case file:read_file(File) of
    {ok, Content} -> Content;
    {error:Error} -> {error: Error}
 end


-module(wy).
-compile(export_all).

read_hlp(File) ->
    try file:read_file(File) of
    {ok, Content} -> Content
    catch
    error:E -> {"Error reading", File, E};
    _:_     -> {allError}
    end.


read(File) ->
    try read_hlp(File) of
    Res -> Res
    catch
    error:Error ->
        Error
    _:_ -> all_exception
    end.
```

When you run above code, you will get `{try_clause,{error,enoent}}`.
The reason is that:
There is a not match in function `read_hlp/1`, so the exception will capture by the called function `read/1`.

Answer (score 2):

Simply because file:read does not issue an exception when the file does not exist, but a tuple {error,Error}. This make sense because a non existing file is something which is frequent, an most of all hard to avoid. You can write:

```
read(File) ->
  case file:read_file(File) of
    {ok, Content} -> Content;
    {error,E} -> {"Error reading", File, E}
  end. %% not very smart since read_file already does the job
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because the `match_clause` error occurs in the "case" part of `try` after `of` which is outside scope where `try` catches errors. The easiest way is to either do as @Pascal suggests or do:

```
read(File) ->
    try
        {ok,Content} = file:read_file(File)
    catch
        error:E -> {"Error reading", File, E};
        _:_     -> {allError}
end.
```

If `file:read_file` cannot read the file then it will return `{error,Reason}` which will cause the match to fail and you will get a `badmatch` error.